# Correct pthread_t initialization and handling

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I understand that `pthread_t` should be treated as an opaque value, however I don't know how to initialize it when used as a class member, and how can I check for its validity.

Consider this code sample:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    pthread_t thread;

    MyClass()
        : thread(0) // Wrong because pthread_t should be an opaque value,
                    // so how should I initialize it?
    {}

    ~MyClass()        
    {
        if( thread ) // Wrong, but how can I verify if it is valid?
            pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    }
};
```

I also understand that if `pthread_create()` fails, the `pthread_t` value may be inconsistent. So I should only rely on the return value from `pthread_create()`. But this means that I should keep this returned value along with `pthread_t` and use it to check thread validity? And in this case, how should I initialize in the class constructor this value?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    pthread_t thread;
    int threadValid;

    MyClass()
        : thread(0), // Wrong because pthread_t should be an opaque value,
                     // so how should I initialize it?
        , threadValid(1) // pthread_create return zero in case of success,
                         // so I can initialize this to any nonzero value?
    {}

    ~MyClass()        
    {
        if( threadValid == 0 ) // Nonzero means thread invalid.
                               // Is this the correct approach?
        {
            pthread_join(thread, NULL);
            threadValid = 1;
        }
    }
};
```

I have a Windows API background, and there a thread has its `HANDLE` value, which may be initialized safely to `NULL`, and can be checked against `NULL`, and if `CreateThread()` fails, it just consistently returns `NULL`. There's no way, with pthreads, to keep this neat and simple approach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276939/is-there-an-invalid-pthread-t-id

Comment: @GilHamilton: that question has no definitive answer on how should I initialize the value and not even on how should I check for thread validity...

Comment: Yes, but it's pretty much an exact duplicate. The real "answer" is that there simply is no reliable "invalid" sentinel value.

Comment: Your idea of using a `threadValid` boolean is fine. (Your code doesn't look correct for that though. Your constructor is making it say "valid" but you haven't called `pthread_create`)

Comment: @GilHamilton OP is using a separate `threadValid` member, which is the correct approach; the question is what syntax to use to initialize the `pthread_t` member to an unspecified value.

Comment: @GilHamilton: the costructor should be correct, as I'm keeping 0 as "thread valid" (as returned by `pthread_create`) and 1 as "thread invalid". The destructor, instead, was wrong (now fixed). The problem with the other question is that, apart saying that there's no reliable "invalid" value, doesn't suggests a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But this means that I should keep this returned value along with pthread_t and use it to check thread validity?

Yes, or more simply keep a boolean, like already mentioned.

> And in this case, how should I initialize in the class constructor this value?

Don't initialize it, it's not mandatory to initialize members in C++.

Comment: OK, a boolean is more readable. But this means that I can't use directly the value returned by `pthread_create`...

Comment: It is guaranteed and documented that the only possible failure code is `-1`?

Comment: @Lorenzo, no, [`pthread_create` returns an error code on error](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html#tag_03_525_05).  However, it does return zero on success, so you can still check for non-zero to indicate failure.

Comment: Right, sorry about that.

Answer (score 10):

`pthread_t` is a C type, so it must have a trivial default constructor; so you can just value-initialize it:

```
    : thread(), // ...
```

Your usage of `threadValid` seems somewhat confused. It would be better to make it a `bool` initially set to `false` and then only set it `true` once `pthread_create` succeeds.

Comment: I like this usage of the default constructor better than not initializing it at all, as suggested by @Pet Johansson, because this way it doesn't seem a forgetfulness during code review.

Comment: @Wizard79: Agreed. This is better than the accepted answer under every C++ coding standard I have ever seen.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can only use a guard variable to know if its value make sense or not.
So for instance you can't use 0 because it would be a valid pthread_t on some systems (DG/UX for instance).
You should have to use something else to know if the value can be used or not, and you should value-initialize it.

If you can compromise on portability (non production code for instance), consider that on Linux and Android pthread_t should be like an int type, and on Darwin it should be an handle, so it would work if you initialize it to 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
pthread_t   thread_handle;
pthread_attr_t  thread_attributes;

pthread_attr_init(&thread_attributes);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&thread_attributes, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

threadValid = (::pthread_create(&thread_handle, &thread_attributes, function, data) == 0);
```

and when shutting it down:

```
if (threadValid) {
    ::pthread_join(thread_handle, 0);
}
```

Don't start your thread [in the constructor](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Doing_Work_in_Constructors) though.

Comment: I don't plan to start the thread in the constructor, but I have to wait for completion in the destructor, so I have to call pthread_join there...

Comment: @Lorenzo: That's perfectly fine.