# Can I check a pthread_t to see if it was initialized by pthread_create, because pthread_join segfaults if pthread_t has not been initialized

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I would like to know if a `pthread_t` has ever been used.  Is there a way to check and see if it is valid before I call `pthread_join`?

This example code segfaults:

```
#include <pthread.h>

static pthread_t pth_freq_loop;

main()
{
    pthread_join(pth_freq_loop, NULL);
}
```

And it can be run as follows:

```
# gcc -lpthread -o pthread pthread.c 
# ./pthread 
Segmentation fault
```

## This is a duplicate of this thread:

[Is there an invalid pthread_t id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276939/is-there-an-invalid-pthread-t-id)

Comment: You can always use a separate variable: `static bool pth_freq_loop_is_valid = false;` Set it `true` after a successful `pthread_create`, and check it before calling `pthread_join`.

Comment: @user3386109: Certainly, but is there a pthread-way to do it?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276939/is-there-an-invalid-pthread-t-id

Comment: Per the POSIX Rationale document: "**It is the application's responsibility to use only valid thread IDs and to keep track of the lifetime of the underlying threads.**" (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html)